# Trying to align a centered div block of images to the left

Tags: html, css

I have multiple images that when the webpage is resized should be left justified but still keep the div block centered.  They are currently all being centered:

See below:

[image]

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```
<div class="widget-content" style="text-align:center;">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="my-img-src.jpg">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="my-img-src.jpg">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="my-img-src.jpg">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="my-img-src.jpg">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="my-img-src.jpg">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="my-img-src.jpg">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="my-img-src.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.widget-content {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}

.medium_thumb_rounded {

  border: 1px solid #B6BCBF;
  /*float: left;*/
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
       border-radius: 3px;  
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you tell it to align left?

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: `.widget-content { text-align:left; }`

Comment: You say the div should be centered, yet the div is 100% width (by default).  What does it mean to center something that is the full width of its container?

Comment: @James Montagne I'm basically trying to keep the left and right margins equal

Comment: @Paul There are no margins defined on the container, or a width or anything else that would create space.  Do you mean you want the block of images centered **within** the div, while still being left aligned within the block?

Comment: @James Montagne Yes, thats exactly what I mean

Comment: @JamesMontagne any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Paul, you may as well delete this question, no need to lose 2 points over it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
<div class="widget-content" style="text-align:center;">
```

Remove the center text align.

Answer (score 0):

Change `text-align:center;` for `text-align:left;`

Answer (score 0):

To keep the div centered try adding this to `.widget-content`:

`margin:auto;`

It will center the div, but have no effect on what's *inside* the div. Use this in conjunction with others' answers that change `text-align:center` to `text-align:left`

Answer (score 0):

To get the behavior I think you're seeking, your DIV needs a max-width.

http://jsfiddle.net/cswbr/

```
style="text-align:center;"
```

To your DIV, Add:

```
margin:0 auto; 
max-width:###px;
```