# How do I center a div block of left aligned images?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a div block of left-aligned images.  Here is the screen shot:

[image]

**The desired result is this**:

[image]

My HTML is this:

```
<div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;padding:10px 0 0 0;">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="medium_thumb.jpg">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="medium_thumb.jpg">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="medium_thumb.jpg">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="medium_thumb.jpg">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="medium_thumb.jpg">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="medium_thumb.jpg">
    <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" id="15" src="medium_thumb.jpg">
</div>
```

Current CSS:

```
.medium_thumb_rounded {

  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #B6BCBF;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 80px;

  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
       border-radius: 3px;  
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally?rq=1

Comment: @Paul simply margin:0 auto should work ,if not than u need to position a div element position:absolute;

Comment: @Maizere Take a look at Georges jsfiddle and you'll see why this doesn't work

Comment: @Paul what is ur problem ,this is how it centers.U want 4 images be in center like square than use photoshop instead

Comment: You actually posted this question twice in one day...

Comment: Take a look at my desired result...this is not the case

Comment: @Marc Audet yes, because I think I may have made it too confusing so I posted an image of the desired result.

Comment: Would you consider a solution that involves JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: @Marc Audet absolutely

Comment: @Paul use photoshop to merge imgs to single img and than center it

Comment: @Maizere The website is responsive so the div could be any width

Comment: Is that person under age? Feels like a violation of some internet use laws.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to align a centered div block of images to the left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487844/trying-to-align-a-centered-div-block-of-images-to-the-left)

Comment: Look on my answer and tell me if it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution using jQuery**

Here is a prototype of how I would solve this problem.

The HTML:

```
<div class="widget-wrap">
    <div class="widget-content">
        <img class="medium_thumb_rounded" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.widget-wrap {
    outline: 2px dashed blue;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 50px;
}
.widget-content {
    outline: 2px dotted blue;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.medium_thumb_rounded {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

and the JavaScipt/jQuery:

```
var $max_w = 600;
var $img_w = 100;

$(window).resize(function () {
contentResizer();
});

// On load, initially, make sure to set the size.
contentResizer();

function contentResizer() {
    var $parent_w = $(".widget-wrap").width();
    if ($parent_w < $max_w) {
        var $set_w = $parent_w;
    } else {
        var $set_w = $max_w;
    }
    var $trimmed_w = Math.floor($set_w / $img_w) * $img_w;
    $(".widget-content").width($trimmed_w);
}
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/jJCak/

**How This Works**

I define a containaing block `div.widget-wrap` that will `text-align: center` its content.
The `.widget-content` is an `inline-block` type and will hold the images.  Use `vertical-align` to get rid of some extra white space due to source code line breaks and so on.

Within the `.widget-content`, I floated the images to the left and set the width to 100px.  You can play with margins and padding as needed.

**The jQuery Action**

There are two parameters, the image width of 100px and the maximum width of images 600px corresponding to 6 images, again you can determine what is best.

Upon resizing the window, the function `contentResizer()` checks the width of the `.widget-wrap` and compares it to the `$max_w`.  If the window shrinks enough, calculate a new width for `.widget-content` by rounding down the with to the next whole number of images.

You also want to make sure that you allow for the case of the window getting larger (alternate clause in `if` statement).

Finally, call the `contentResizer()` once upon loading the page.

**Why This Can't Be Done With CSS Alone**

The CSS parser will not determine the width of a containing block based on the content of the descendant elements (except for tables, which is uses a different sizing algorithm).

In this application, if you set the `width` to a fixed value and use `margin: 0 auto`, the block will center.  If you don't set the width and use `margin: 0 Xpx`, you again will have a centered block with left/right margin of Xpx.

However, if you rely on `width: auto` and `margin: 0 auto`, the CSS spec does not specify what to do, so the width fills up the width of its parent container.

The reason for this is that the CSS parser formats the content from left to right, top to bottom in a single a pass (except for tables).  Ideally, the CSS parser would set the container width, lay out the images, and then go back and calculate the width, and then shrink-to-fit the container width, BUT this is not how things work.

There is a shrink-to-fit algorithm used in table-cells and in some cases for absolutely positioned elements that are overflowing, but this did not help in your application.

Comment: Your very welcome! This is a common problem and worth tackling.  By the way, if the user had disabled JavaScript, the site will still look okay, just slightly off center, and that is okay.

Answer (score 1):

If you give your div a width, then set your margin: 0 auto; you should be set to go.

Comment: The site is responsive so I can't give it a set width...the parent width can change

Comment: You might be able to though, if you put display:block on your div, and then put text-align: center; on body but still retaining your text-align:left on your div it may have the desired effect.

Comment: Try adding a border to the parent div and you'll see that the block of images is no longer centered...maybe this isn't possible with just CSS

Answer (score 1):

It's easy

You need add one more div, let's call it `parent` and second add class `children` to your existing div

```
div.children {
    width: 80%; //change it for what you want
    text-align: left;
}
div.parent {
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tuxH7/5/

Comment: If you add some outline to your containers, you will see that there is extra white space to the right of the images... see http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/tuxH7/6/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using JavaScript to add the widths of all the items in the first row. Then set the wrapper around the images to be that width. That way, if the wrapper has margin:auto; on it, it will be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing too many complicated answers here.
This should work, or at least answer the OP's question:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="medium_thumb.jpg" />
            <img src="medium_thumb.jpg" />
            <img src="medium_thumb.jpg" />
            <img src="medium_thumb.jpg" />
            <img src="medium_thumb.jpg" />
            <img src="medium_thumb.jpg" />
            <img src="medium_thumb.jpg" />
            <img src="medium_thumb.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .content{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
    }

    .content img{
        float:left;
        display:block;
        width:25%; /* This controls how many you want per row*/
    }
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qV7aK/)

Comment: It's good answer but OP probably don't want scale images with page resolution.

Answer (score -2):

just put the following attribute in your css class or in the style section

> align: center

Comment: The `align` property doesn't exist.